# Reason: The user who attempted to complete the task is not the user to whom the task is assigned

Tags: approval

I am using the OOB workflow "Approval - SharePoint 2010". I assigned a user, say UserA, to approve a file.

A task is created and the assignee is UserA. I login as UserB and try to approval the task. After I press "approve" I get an error saying I am not the assignee. In the workflow history UserB is rejected and logged the reason.
(Reason: The user who attempted to complete the task is not the user to whom the task is assigned.)

It is working as expected. However, when I login with the site owner and site collection admin, I am able to approve the task without error. Both accounts are not the task assignee.

May I know what's the logic behind? Is it depends on some permission level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Site Owners and Site Collection Administrators are supposed to do administrative tasks in a Site Collection. That's why one should be careful making users owners or SC admins. It's important that owners have the necessary knowledge of SharePoint before they obtain an owner role. Especially since they have the permission to do administrative work and could, if they don't have knowledge, destroy (and delete) of the Site Collection.

Comment: Benny, may I ask a side track question. Can I restrict the user start the workflow not to change "assignee"? I have setup "Managers" the deafult assignee but it seems any user start the workflow can change the assignee to anyone including himself.

Comment: @Mark Unfortunately not out of the box. You could hide it with inline CSS or inline JavaScript, but for this you need to make sure that those who should be able to change can do so. You can solve it through [SPServices on CodePlex](https://spservices.codeplex.com/)